# css3 simple animation not working

Tags: css

I have an animation with css3

```
@keyframes aia2{
from{ opacity:1}
to{ opacity:0}
}/* similar with other prefixes */



.animate{
-webkit-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
   -moz-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
     -o-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
        animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate; 
}
```

html

```
<ul>
<li class="item" id="term1">1</li>
<li class="item" id="term2">2</li>
<li class="item" id="term3">3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to animate li but it is not working

```
$(".item").removeClass("animate");
$(specified id).addClass("animate");
```

I am adding animate class to the an li and removing for other li tags.

I also tried with setTimeout, no use.

how I can get it?

Comment: What is `aia2`? Post that also in the question... First of all, is there an `aia2` keyframe???

Comment: is there a keyframe aia2 in your css

Comment: keyframe animation name aia2

Comment: @user1834809 can you post it here?

Comment: check it with animation

Comment: Yes, it is not working... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding and removing classes change animation play state. using css3 `animation-play-state` property

reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-play-state

Answer (score 0):

and if you use this:

```
@keyframes aia2{
     0%   { opacity: 1; }
     50%  { opacity: 0.5; }
     100% { opacity: 0; }
    }
```

and you could use @-moz-keyframes, @-webkit-keyframes and @-o-keyframes for the different kits

you can find [my test here](http://jsfiddle.net/waUgK/) and it's going on forever

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this works. But only once:

**CSS**

```
@keyframes myfirst
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-o-keyframes myfirst /* Opera */
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

.animate{
    -webkit-animation-name: myfirst;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: infinite;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="item animate" id="term1">1</li>
    <li class="item" id="term2">2</li>
    <li class="item" id="term3">3</li>
</ul>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ACUEg/